# recordEditFrom - Address Field is disabled in Site as a Guest

Tags: lightning, lightning-out

When using Lightning Out and recordEditForm, the Mailing Address fields on Contact object is disabled even though the permissions are set on the Guest Profile. All other fields are fine.

[image]

Manually removing the "disabled" attribute and putting the value actually saves it. Is this another SFDC bug or am I missing something?

The code is as follows:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" objectApiName="Contact" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
...
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="MailingAddress" fieldName="MailingAddress"/>
...    
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

If I update the above to the following, it starts working OK, so this is not permission issue:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" objectApiName="Contact" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
...
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="MailingCountry" fieldName="MailingCountry"/>
...    
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Comment: Can you provide the snippet of the code which is causing this and the fix how you manage to enable it?

Comment: @JayantDas I've just updated with the relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I too am facing the same issue, but a bit different.

I'm able to access the BillingAddress Field of Account Object, but unable to access the ShippingAddress. It's rendered as readonly/disabled.

Let me know if you'd any luck getting it resolved. Refer screenshot attached.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

MailingAddress is a compound field which internally consist of

Individual field reference of below fields will work.

```
MailingCountry
MailingCountryCode --- Use if you want pick list.
MailingState
MailingStateCode --- But this will not supported as it is a dependent picklist
MailingStreet
MailingPostalCode
```

Comment: I understand that it works as individual fields, and that's the current workaround as per my original question. My question is why putting MailingAddress doesn't work? Salesforce provides UI around the compound field, hence that's the preference.